# Get client's IP address from an HTTPS hosted website using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, https, ip-address

I am working on an application where I need to save Client's IP Address. I have used the following code:

```
function GetIPAddress() {

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    hostipInfo = xmlhttp.responseText.split("\n");
    for (i = 0; hostipInfo.length >= i; i++) {
        ipAddress = hostipInfo[i].split(":");
        if (ipAddress[0] == "IP") {
            return ipAddress[1];
        }
    }
    return "0";
}
```

Now, this code works fine when I check it on localhost, but when I put this for testing in an HTTPS environment, this doesn't work.

Kindly Help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the return value of your request? I think, the problem in the PHP file.

Comment: Hi, alex, I've used another code as well, 
`code`

    $.getJSON("http://jsonip.com?callback=?", function (data) {
            ipAddress = data.ip;
        });
`code`

Even this doesn't work on https. The codes do not return any value, instead, the functionality stops and results in a pause in the running application.

Comment: If you're trying to get insecure content from a ssl-website, browsers will block that. _hostip.info_ obviously doesn't support SSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://www.freegeoip.net/ They provide a service where you can look up the geolocation of an IP,  If no IP or hostname is provided, then your own IP is looked up.

Jquery :

```
$.get('freegeoip.net/{format}/').success(function(response) {
//code to retrieve ip
var ip = response.ip;
});
```

Note: Supported formats are: csv, xml, json and jsonp

Comment: Hi Aman, thanks for your reply, when I'm checking my IP on http://www.whatsmyip.org/, then it's showing a totally different IP Address than the freegoip.net service. 
I might be wrong using it, or maybe I'm understanding it wrong. 
Kindly clear

Comment: I am getting the same IP on both the websites. try again by clicking http://www.whatsmyip.org/ and  http://www.freegeoip.net

Comment: Got it! Thanks! I'll check it after deploying my code and will let you know the result.

Comment: This one worked! Thanks Aman! I got to know later that my IP address keeps changing because of being registered to multiple ports. Thanks again!